# PHP is listing files with readable permissions but cannot file_get_contents or require_once

Tags: php, drupal-6, require-once

It is a Drupal site, where includes/module.inc runs a loop over files in the registry and attempts `require_once()`. For a number of files this is failing, even though the file permissions are correct and the file *should* be readable.

I've added debug code to the loop to output to check file perms and contents:

```
  // Debug code
  print "$file perms:" . substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms($file)), -4) . "<br>";
  print "$file contents:<br>" . htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents($file)) . "<hr>";

  // Original Code
  require_once $file;
```

It outputs the file permissions as well as well as the file contents before attempting the require_once. Different pages are failing on different files, the homepage for instance is outputting:

```
./sites/default/modules/cck/includes/content.token.inc perms:0755
./sites/default/modules/cck/includes/content.token.inc contents:

[filecontent]

./sites/default/modules/filefield/filefield.token.inc perms:0644
./sites/default/modules/filefield/filefield.token.inc contents:

[filecontent]

./sites/default/modules/getid3/getid3.install perms:0644
./sites/default/modules/getid3/getid3.install contents:

[NO FILE CONTENT]
```

So for some reason `./sites/default/modules/getid3/getid3.install` allegedly has the permission to be readable, but isn’t.

Different paths show different files as being problematic:

```
/
    ./sites/default/modules/getid3/getid3.install perms:0644
/admin
    ./sites/default/modules/webform/components/date.inc perms:0644
/user
    ./sites/default/modules/cck/includes/content.crud.inc perms:0755
```

**EDIT:**

Note above that `./sites/default/modules/cck/includes/content.token.inc` is readable but `./sites/default/modules/cck/includes/content.crud.inc` gives error, here's the directory listing for those files (including `--context` to check for SELinux)

```
# ll --context
total 168
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root ?  4096 Sep 28 05:50 ./
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root ?  4096 Nov  6  2013 ../
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root ? 72264 Nov  6  2013 content.admin.inc*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root ? 26307 Sep 28 03:13 content.crud.inc*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root ?  7181 Nov  6  2013 content.devel.inc*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root ?  3868 Nov  6  2013 content.diff.inc*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root ? 15914 Nov  6  2013 content.node_form.inc*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root ? 12550 Nov  6  2013 content.rules.inc*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root ?  6246 Nov  6  2013 content.token.inc*
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root ?  4096 Nov  6  2013 panels/
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root ?  4096 Nov  6  2013 views/
```

The modified date of `crud` is me commenting the code for testing after the errors occurred, but it is back to as it was now.

**EDIT 2:**

It seems that trying to access `robots.txt` directly is also forbidden. Not sure if this is the same problem, but again the file looks like it should be perfectly readable.

```
# ll robots.txt 
-rw-r--r-- 1 6226 6226 1521 Aug  6 18:07 robots.txt
```

**EDIT 3:**

Looks like the problem was AppArmor, which I suppose is similar to SELinux. Changing from `aa-enforce` to `aa-complain` resolved the issue.

Comment: Are you sure the file isn't simply empty? Do you get any warnings or errors?

Comment: Also, I should note that this site had no problems until a couple days ago.

Comment: It should work, so the only explanation I could give at this point is: seLinux :)

Comment: Ahh yes I thought the same thing, I tried `sestatus` and `cat /etc/sysconfig/selinux` but both imply it's not installed?

Comment: Added output of `ll -context`

Comment: When you use `error_reporting(~0);`, does it issue any warnings?

Comment: In my code edit I've also added `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);`, the first of anything to show is the Fatal error

Comment: `file_get_contents()` doesn't raise a fatal error if the file can't be read.

Comment: Sorry, I should clarify, the original `require_once()` is run after my added `file_get_contents()`, so that's where the Fatal is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps some selinux cmd like might get this running :

```
semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_httpd_sys_content_t '/var/lib/myapp(/.*)?'
restorecon -R -v /var/lib/myapp
```

Where /var/lib/myapp is your ./ directory

Comment: SELinux is not installed, so wouldn't that mean that installing it would only increase restrictions?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem was AppArmor, which I suppose is similar to SELinux. Changing from `aa-enforce` to `aa-complain` resolved the issue.